# Regex minify <pre> tag content

Tags: c#, regex, minify

I'm using [this filter](http://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/minify-html-with-net-mvc-actionfilter/) to minify my HTML. Unfortunately, that filter also minifies code inside `<pre>` tags, but I don't want them to be changed. How I can change the regexes so they don't minify any code inside `<pre>` tags?

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\n\s*", "\n");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\>\s*\<\s*", "><");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<!--(.*?)-->", "");   //Remove comments
```

Comment: Have you contacted the creator? or left a comment on their site with the same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the developer of that filter provides this option, you can try the following: You can add a nested [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to your regexes that precludes them from matching if a `</pre>` tag follows (unless a `<pre>` tag comes first). For the first three regexes, that means:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)\s+(?!(?:(?!</?pre\b).)*</pre>)", " ");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)\s*\n\s*(?!(?:(?!</?pre\b).)*</pre>)", "\n");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)\s*\>\s*\<\s*(?!(?:(?!</?pre\b).)*</pre>)", "><");
```

**Explanation** of the lookahead assertion:

```
(?!          # Assert that the following regex can't be matched here:
 (?:         # Match...
  (?!        #  (unless the following can be matched:
   </?pre\b  #  an opening or closing <pre> tag)
  )          #  (End of inner lookahead assertion)
  .          # ...any character (the (?s) makes sure that this includes newlines)
 )*          # Repeat any number of times
 </pre>      # Match a closing <pre> tag
)            # (End of outer lookahead assertion)
```

For the fourth regex, we must first make sure that `.*?` doesn't match any `<pre>` tags either

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)<!--((?:(?!</?pre\b).)*?)-->(?!(?:(?!</?pre\b).)*</pre>)", "");
```

Other than that, the regex works just as above.